# Could someone explain to me what these last two log events are and what their data is?

Tags: transactions

I've determined what the first three events are and what their data represents, however I've tried searching for the last two hashes through google and through using a Keccak hash converter and some function signatures but I can't seem to figure out what those last two log entries are representing.

```
"logs": [
        {
            "transactionIndex": 14,
            "blockNumber": 12741073,
            "transactionHash": "0x9b64134984bf22c87bc7ad7a66a66d1a368e368c0587ddcebf74c8a2e66cd74d",
            "address": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2", //WETH
            "topics": [
                "0xe1fffcc4923d04b559f4d29a8bfc6cda04eb5b0d3c460751c2402c5c5cc9109c", //Deposit
                "0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d" //Uniswap v2 router
            ],
            "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007c5850872380000", //Deposit amount - 0.56 WETH
            "logIndex": 21,
            "blockHash": "0xf81ed64a92bbaeac111afe4d77346e47daca11c7baee3af8d4e42f36a6ba7ae4"
        },
        {
            "transactionIndex": 14,
            "blockNumber": 12741073,
            "transactionHash": "0x9b64134984bf22c87bc7ad7a66a66d1a368e368c0587ddcebf74c8a2e66cd74d",
            "address": "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2", //WETH
            "topics": [
                "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", //Transfer
                "0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d", //Uniswap v2 router
                "0x00000000000000000000000030ac70e2dc5092f64031685bb23d50f782c27566" //Eth-Floki pairing on uni
            ],
            "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007c5850872380000", //Transfer 0.56 WETH to FLOKI
            "logIndex": 22,
            "blockHash": "0xf81ed64a92bbaeac111afe4d77346e47daca11c7baee3af8d4e42f36a6ba7ae4"
        },
        {
            "transactionIndex": 14,
            "blockNumber": 12741073,
            "transactionHash": "0x9b64134984bf22c87bc7ad7a66a66d1a368e368c0587ddcebf74c8a2e66cd74d",
            "address": "0xb1F4b66104353eC63D8d59D3da42C0b4Fb06E7f3", //FLOKI
            "topics": [
                "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", //Transfer
                "0x00000000000000000000000030ac70e2dc5092f64031685bb23d50f782c27566", //Eth-Floki pairing on uni
                "0x0000000000000000000000007cbbba14c573fa52aadad44c7ae8085dc0764ebd" //Invoking wallet
            ],
            "data": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014440a24cc81735", //Amount of FLOKI transferred to Invoking wallet
            "logIndex": 23,
            "blockHash": "0xf81ed64a92bbaeac111afe4d77346e47daca11c7baee3af8d4e42f36a6ba7ae4"
        },
        {
            "transactionIndex": 14,
            "blockNumber": 12741073,
            "transactionHash": "0x9b64134984bf22c87bc7ad7a66a66d1a368e368c0587ddcebf74c8a2e66cd74d",
            "address": "0x30Ac70e2dc5092f64031685bb23D50f782C27566",
            "topics": [
                "0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1"
            ],
            "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000028f49cc938e0a6f8a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c8e9cff15248bbb42",
            "logIndex": 24,
            "blockHash": "0xf81ed64a92bbaeac111afe4d77346e47daca11c7baee3af8d4e42f36a6ba7ae4"
        },
        {
            "transactionIndex": 14,
            "blockNumber": 12741073,
            "transactionHash": "0x9b64134984bf22c87bc7ad7a66a66d1a368e368c0587ddcebf74c8a2e66cd74d",
            "address": "0x30Ac70e2dc5092f64031685bb23D50f782C27566",
            "topics": [
                "0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822",
                "0x0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d", //Uniswap v2 router
                "0x0000000000000000000000007cbbba14c573fa52aadad44c7ae8085dc0764ebd" //Invoking wallet
            ],
            "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e9f15f84dea400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007c5850872380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019550cadffa1d010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "logIndex": 25,
            "blockHash": "0xf81ed64a92bbaeac111afe4d77346e47daca11c7baee3af8d4e42f36a6ba7ae4"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You need the contract code or ABI to be able to decode logs

Answer (score 2):

You can search the first topic in the log entry in the [Ethereum Signature Database](https://www.4byte.directory/event-signatures/?bytes_signature=0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1)

- `0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1`

  ```
  Sync(uint112,uint112)
  ```
- `0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822`

  ```
  Swap(address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,address)
  ```

Also with the contract address [`0x30Ac70e2dc5092f64031685bb23D50f782C27566`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x30ac70e2dc5092f64031685bb23d50f782c27566#code) you can search the definitions if the source code is verified. In this case it give us:

```
event Swap(
    address indexed sender,
    uint amount0In,
    uint amount1In,
    uint amount0Out,
    uint amount1Out,
    address indexed to
);
event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);
```